# Routing issue in Laravel after shifting the method

Tags: php, laravel, routes, path, controller

OLD:-
The method `autocompletelocation()` was available in `SupplierController`(`app\Http\Controllers\Site\SupplierController.php`).
So the below code was in `\routes\web.php`:-

```
$router->get('autocompletelocation', 'Site\SupplierController@autocompletelocation');
```

NEW:-
Now, I have shifted this method `autocompletelocation()` to `ViewsHealper.php`(`app\Helpers\ViewsHelper.php`).

Can anyone please let me know how can I modify this below code as per my above new Change:-

```
$router->get('autocompletelocation', 'Site\SupplierController@autocompletelocation');
```

Comment: You do not use helper functions to handle routing requests, that's what controller methods are for. If needed, call the helper function from within the controller method.

Answer (score -1):

In the SupplierController, put this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use app\Helpers;

class SupplierController extends Controller
{

    use ViewsHelper;
}
```

After that, in your controller you have access to your Helper class.

Another way is to add your Helper to composer.json

```
 "autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app\Helpers\ViewsHelper.php"
    ]
```

Then run
composer dump-autoload

And you can have access to your helper without needing to instantiate the class